# I do not understand what SSDT do as opposed to (or not?) SSMS and SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

So all my searches, regardless of combinations of keywords, end up showing me articles that assume I know all about SSDT.

Can someone please explain to me...

1. Where they can be found in VS2015 (or 2013) or elsewhere.
2. Were they created specifically for VS - I thought I read that some time ago?
3. Why use them instead of SSMS?
4. Why use them instead of or what is the relationship to SQL Server Object Explorer?

Answer (score 4):

Basically there are different project types for SSDT, they are visual studio project types and so have been created specifically for visual studio.

If you are developing SSIS or SSAS then you need to use SSDT (or pay for something like the varigence mist product), now it seems like you are talking about SSDT for database projects which is a template that lets you create tables, views, stored procedures (and quite a few other types).

SSDT for database projects is normally what people talk about when they say "why should I use ssdt over ssms", what I normally say is that ssms is an administration tool, and ssdt is the developer tool.

If you have a simple database and it is not very complex then ssdt is probably an overhead you don't need. If you have a complex database where you need to make changes to - ssdt is great because it gives you:

- Compile time verification (you know the code will deploy and run, in ssms if you mis-type a table name in a procedure you won't know until run time)
- Find all references (to see where a table, column, procedure etc) is used you can right click it and find all the references. This makes it easy to see where an object is used and if you have create table a.a and create table b.a - it will only find references to the one you want, rather than a string search for tables called a
- Refactoring, use ssdt to rename a table or column (refactor->rename) and when you deploy it will generate a sp_rename (correctly) rather than dropping and creating the table - this is great and means you can tiidy up your database as you go.

For a full rundown of why I think you should use ssdt see:

https://the.agilesql.club/blogs/ed-elliott/2016-01-05/What-Is-SSDT-Why-Should-I-Bother

Ed

Answer (score 3):

1. As it is said already that it is Visual Studio plugin/extension. You can easily find it by googling "download SSDT";
2. I did not get the question, but if as far as I understood then SSDT can be used with VS only;
3. SSMS benefits: easier for Query writing and DB administration;
   SSDT benefits: Version controlling, offline development, object validation and reference check, automated builds/deployment, and many many more. 
   In 2 words: SSDT for DB development, SSMS for adhoc queries and DB administration ( you can do many things with any of these tools, but at least for me it is easier to use them for these purposes)
4. Did not get the question, maybe I already answered it in scope of 3)

Answer (score 0):

SSDT is SQL Server Data Tool, which is a plug-in for visual studio for developing BI projects (SSIS, SSRS and SSAS). It is not anything like Object Explorer.

When you install SQL Server, it installs a light-weight visual studio IDE on your machine and also installs SSDT as add-in so you can create/open BI projects.

SSDT is also available for download to install on machines w/o SQL Server. You need to have VS 2008 and later to use it. Each visual studio has it's own version.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's not for me as I have no idea what a BI project is. BTW VS2015 installs SSDT automatically I am led to believe.

Answer (score 0):

Like "Flicker" said, it's a plugin for Visual Studio for developing: SSIS (ETL), SSRS (Reporting) and SSAS (Cubes)

When you install SQL Server you need to select SSDT for installation. It's not installed automatically. I

You can see SSDT plugin when you are creating a new project in Visual Studio. You can then choose to create a "Business Intelligence" project, like:
- Analysis Services (SSAS)
- Reporting Services (SSRS)
- Integration Services (SSIS)

You can also setup database projects which can be very handy. The database compare tool is excellent!

Comment: What is a "You can also setup database projects which can be very handy."
Is that different to creating a DB with tables using SSMS?

Comment: Yes it's different. With SSMS you are connecting to an instance. Visual Studio has it's own instance where you can create databases. Offcourse you can create tables and other objects just like in SSMS. In VS you create database projects so you can connect from SSRS/SSAS/SSIS projects. It's just for developers so they can develop on 1 machine with 1 tool like VS>

Comment: I have been developing projects with MS SQL + Visual Studio for many years, but I have never used SSDT. SSMS is perfectly ok. The only thing I can't get right with it without third-party extensions is schema comparison. That's the only reason I want to take a look at SSDT. Schema comparison is not important to me. I can also create the change queries by hand. Just wanted to see if I can save some time here.

Comment: Ok. Schema comparison is nice if you have to work with entity framework code that for whatever reason doesn't use automatic code first migration.